# Converting two integers to an array of binaries?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a machine-learning experiment and I'm trying to figure out a fast function that does this:

It takes two integers between 0-99 and retruns an array of binaries:

```
var binaries = convert(12, 33);
console.log(binaries) //outputs [0,1,0,1,1,0]
```

`binaries` will then be compared to two other binaries to see witch it's matching best:

```
var 1 = [0,1,1,1,1,0] // 5 matches
var 2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0] // 3 matches, 1 wins!
```

The first values will be fead in and the other will be randomly changed in order to find one that is as ideal as possible. Ideal means that based on the input it will create an output that picks the right one out of 1 and 2 as often as possible. The length of the generated array is not known. How should convert work?

Comment: You might want to reword this question it's a bit confusing, are you wanting to return a concatenated binary value from the `convert` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would look like this:

```
var arrToTest = [1,1,1];
function intToBinaryArray(num){
    var binary = num.toString(2);
    var arr = [];
    for (var i=0; i<binary.length; i++){
        arr[i] = parseInt(binary.charAt(i));
    }
    return arr;
}
function binaryComparison(a,b){
    var result = 0;
    a.forEach(function(r,i){
        if(r === b[i]){
            result++;
        }
    })
    return result;
}
console.log(
    binaryComparison(arrToTest,intToBinaryArray(7)) + ' out of ' +
    arrToTest.length + ' matched.'
);
```

You can add as many arrays to test against as you wish, you can then loop through them. The one with the highes value from `binaryComparison` would then have the best match.

**EDIT:**
I missed the partial comparison part, I will add that in a moment.

**EDIT2:**
Added comparison part.

Comment: thx, I was mostly interested in intToBinaryArray, it should take two values, and I'm not really sure what arr[i] = parseInt(binary.charAt(i));
 does... But it looks promising!

Comment: After using `num.toString(2)`, the binary will be displayed as a String such as "001", since an array with integers is required I loop through each character, convert it back to integer with `parseInt` and assign it to the array with `arr[i] =`.